# Group with an interesting property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $ (G,\cdot ) $ be a group and let $ a $ be the only element of the group which has order 2. Prove that $ a\cdot x=x\cdot a,\forall x\in G $ .

Comment: @C.Falcon then find it and mark this question as a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Show that $x a x^{-1}$ has order $2$ for all $x \in G$.